# В чем проблема не работает поиск по Бд и вывод на страницу

Tags: php

***форма ввода***

```html
<div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="search-input" id="string" placeholder="Искать" />
    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event)">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

***api.php***

```php
case 'metafind': {
    $string = $_GET['string'];
    $list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `sub_meta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'Названия'");
    while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)) {
        if($item['meta_value'] == $string) {
            $id = $item['post_id'];
            $do = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `sub_meta` WHERE `post_id` = '$id' ");
            $find = mysqli_fetch_assoc($do);
            $prepare = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `sub_meta` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
            $name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prepare);
            $arrr[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'post_id' => $item['post_id'], 'coords' => $find['meta_value'], 'sub_name' => $name['sub_name']);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($arrr);
} break;
```

***Ошибка в том что форма как буд-то не активна не работает в чем ошибка***

> Мне нужно чтобы форма отправляла переменю и это переменная искала
>   совпадения с собой в таблице как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Для инпута вы не указали name

Comment: А какой name указывать то есть I'd?

Comment: Почитайте о том как происходит отправка форм

Comment: для того чтобы отправить форму на сервер вам надо прописать атрибут `name` у тэга `input`, потому что  `id` не равно `name` и название поля берется именно с `name`, проще говоря вы не назвали поле.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в input добавить аттрибут name="string"

```
<input type="text" class="search-input" id="string" name="string" placeholder="Искать" />
```

*P.S.: Если атрибут id не используется для поиска этого элемента JS либо установки стилей, можно удалить его. При передачи параметров используя формы, достать эти параметры можно по аттрибуту name в input-ах*